# apacheの停止・起動が調子悪い

Tags: apache, xampp

httpd.conf

```
Include /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

上記設定にしていましたが、いつの間にかapacheのコントロールパネルでstopをしてもstopにならずにrunningのままで、httpd-vhosts.confで設定している
ServerName ■■■■-localhostにアクセスしても403になります。
以前までは正常にアクセスできていました。

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

に設定するとstopもstartも正常にできますが、URL localhostにアクセスすると
Error 403がでます。

Includeの先頭に#をつけvirtualhostを閉じて、localhostにアクセスすると
XAMPPのWelcome to XAMPP for OS X 5.6.37の画面が表示されます。

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
```

最終的にvirtualhostで設定しているURLにアクセスできるようにしたいですが、
今apacheに何が起きているのでしょうか。
お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

hosts

```
127.0.0.1 ■■■■-localhost
```

環境

```
macOS HighSierra macOS HighSierra 10.13.6
XAMPP 5.6.37
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

を、
`Include /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
にし、
xamppコントローラパネルのapacheをstartさせたら、URLにアクセスできました。
apacheの停止・起動も正常になりました。